# ImageIO.read return null with IKVM

Tags: java, javax.imageio, ikvm

i have a Library Written in java (huge and used all over the company) and i have to use it under C#. I used Ikvm (ikvmc utility) to generate the generate a Dll.

Java Lib use a lot of pdfbox function and, in one of these function, i have a nullpointer exception popping out ONLY when using throug .NET (so i link the dll generated via IKVM). If I use the code directly from Java it goes smooth.

```
private void calcualteImageSize(InputStream fis) throws IOException {

 BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(fis);

 int width = bimg.getWidth();
 int height = bimg.getHeight();

 sigImgHeight = (float) height;
 sigImgWidth = (float) width;

}
```

After this

```
 BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(fis);
```

bimg is null while fis is not null ( i have checked it).
The same stament used throught IKVM in some point of the Java library return OK, only the one used into pdfbox pop up the exception.
I think it could be a problem using IKVM but i cant point it.

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSignDesigner.calcualteImageSize(PDVisibleSignDesigner.java:325)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSignDesigner.signatureImageStream(PDVisibleSignDesigner.java:303)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.visible.PDVisibleSignDesigner.<init>(PDVisibleSignDesigner.java:98)
at it.getPDVisibleSigProperties(SignedPDF.java:2685)
at it.addSignatureRevision(SignedPDF.java:2413)
at it.Lib.Test(Lib.java:442)
at cli.Porting.Test.Main(Test.cs:13)
at cli.System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Unknown Source)
at cli.System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(Unknown Source)
at cli.Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly(Unknown Source)
at cli.Porting.Test.Main(Test.cs:13)
at cli.System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Unknown Source)
at cli.System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(Unknown Source)
at cli.Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly(U
nknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Done!

Comment: The image format is of interest. Every image type is added as plugin; jpg and png being available out of the box. `ImageIO` can query for an image type (and its readers). Maybe some type reverts to native code.

Comment: I have assured (or at least i'm really confident) that the image is a PNG

Comment: @Razlo3p Can you dump the bytes of the stream (`fis`) to disk, to verify that the problem isn't with this particular image? As Joop says, PNG support is built into `ImageIO` (along with GIF, JPEG, BMP and WBMP).

Comment: Can you debug using IKVM, to see what really happens inside `ImageIO.read(...)`?

Comment: @haraldK i don't know how to follow the code generated Trough Ikvm, can you tell me more about it? i'm inspecting deeper the Issue with system.out and so on... but is really not so easy and practice

Comment: @Razlo3p Sorry, no, I don't have any experience with IKVM. That's part of why I'm asking... I do know a bit or two about ImageIO though. ;-) If you can't debug, start by dumping the PNG to disk to verify 100% that it is in fact a PNG.

Comment: Still no Clue how to fix this. The problem is still under IKVM traduction, since all ImageIO function fails